# Why small size Image View not overlapping over the large Image View inside constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

[image]I am trying to overlap small imageview over large imageview. I have tested this code in emulator and real device. nothing works.
XML code snippet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/itemCard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- large ImageView -->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_145sdp"
    android:background="@color/grey_lighter"
    android:elevation="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/dummy" />


 <!-- small ImageView -->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/typ_rounded_view"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_video" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Constraint Layout gradle:

```
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
```

Android Studio Version : 4.2.2

Comment: can you share preview of how exactly you want to overlap?

Comment: @Bhavin Please check preview attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout this is happening due to the elevation in large image. For example as you can see current elevation of large image is 1 and small image is 0 due to this large image will be elevated. to resolve this you can remove elevation attribute from large image or else also add elevation in small image as per your requirement

in following i have added elevation to both ImageView.

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/itemCard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- large ImageView -->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey_lighter"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


<!-- small ImageView -->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/typ_round_view"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**typ_round_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/grey_darker" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="30dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="18dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

</shape>
```

the above layout will give you same result as your requirement

[image: Output result]

Answer (score 0):

In my case both are overlapping. I reduced the code a bit. Cutting off unnecessary attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/itemCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- large ImageView -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_image" />


    <!-- small ImageView -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_image2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image: Result]